# Defining constants based on route in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

We're currently working on a Laravel 5 project that hosts separate sub-websites. These separate websites are grouped in the routes and share common prefixes. For example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'siteone', 'namespace' => 'SiteOneNamespace'], function() {
    Route::get('routeone', 'SiteOneController@index');
    Route::get('routetwo', 'SiteOneController@indextwo');
    (...)
}

Route::group(['prefix' => 'sitetwo', 'namespace' => 'SiteTwoNamespace'], function() {
    Route::get('routeone', 'SiteTwoController@index');
    Route::get('routetwo', 'SiteTwoController@indextwo');
    (...)
}
```

A third party library is used by all sites in this project. This third party library relies on PHP constants for its settings. However, not all sub-sites will have the same settings, as some of the settings will differ depending on each site.

So my question is: Is there a way that I can define these constants based on the 'prefix' value of each sub-site route, in a way that these constants will be available in the controllers?

Something like:

```
$routePrefix = getRoutePrefix();

if($routePrefix == 'siteone') {
   define("LIBRARY_SETTING", "value_for_site_one");
}
elseif($routePrefix == 'sitetwo') {
   define("LIBRARY_SETTING", "value_for_site_two");
}
```

I know that we can probably do this in the routes.php file, but I think there must be a more elegant solution for this, as the routes file isn't supposed to be a place to define constants. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a middleware:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CreateConstant
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $name, $value)
    {
        define($name, $value);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then register it in the `App\Http\Kernel` class:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other route middleware...
    'constant' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CreateConstant',
];
```

Finally, use it on your route groups:

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'siteone',
    'namespace' => 'SiteOneNamespace',
    'middleware' => 'constant:LIBRARY_SETTING,value_1',
], function() {
    // routes
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'sitetwo',
    'namespace' => 'SiteTwoNamespace',
    'middleware' => 'constant:LIBRARY_SETTING,value_2',
], function() {
    // routes
});
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. When I tried it, I kept on getting this error message:

ReflectionException in Container.php line 779:
Class constant:LIBRARY_SETTING,value_1 does not exist.

I tried running composer dump-autoload, but that didn't help. Also ran:
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize

With no success.

Comment: Chances are the library is being loaded before the request is even dealt with. The answer I can think is defining a way of assigning the global in .htaccess if you're using Apache or something similar for nginx

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. The error message is about the middleware class not existing. If it was an error with the library, it would simply complain about attempting to use a constant that doesn't exist. It seems like the middleware is not being properly loaded, even though I registered it in App\Http\Kernel as suggested.

Comment: @vascaino - Are you using a recent version of Laravel 5.1? Laravel 5.0 did not have support for middleware parameters.

Comment: @JosephSilber It looks like that's it. We're using Laravel 5.0 and not 5.1. Bummer, will have to look for another solution. I appreciate the help, though.

Comment: @vascaino - No bummer. Just use [a before filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters). It's more-or-less the same thing.